# Grub appeared out of nowhere. How do I remove it?

Tags: boot, release-juno, grub

I installed Juno a couple weeks ago on a new laptop. I have elementaryOS on one hard drive and Windows 10 on a second hard drive -- no partitioning, just physically separate drives.

When I initially installed eOS, it didn't install Grub, I don't think. At least, the Grub menu didn't appear when I booted; it would boot automatically into eOS and, if I needed Windows, I would manually select it from the BIOS boot menu. This is how I like it, because I barely use Windows.

Today, I booted up and the Grub menu came up after the logo splash screen. I don't know if it got automatically installed in an OS update maybe? But as I understand it, it should be unnecessary, because my OSs are on separate physical drives; is that not the case?

I've searched around for how to remove Grub but all of the instructions I've found are for removing Linux *entirely*, which of course I don't want to do. How do I go back to booting directly to Linux? And, how do I prevent Grub from getting automatically added like this, if indeed it is part of a routine OS update?

Answer (score 1):

### Concepts

is the key word here

---

> no partitioning, just physically separate drives.

I understand what you mean but even one is a **Partition** that has a **Format**

> When I initially installed eOS, it didn't install Grub, I don't think.

Grub comes with eOS as default (AFAIK every Linux distro comes with Grub), and If you have multiple OS installed the menu will show as default

> At least, the Grub menu didn't appear when I booted; it would boot automatically into eOS and,

Don't know why didn't showed up, but if you have multiple systems is normal to have it. Probably the first boot didn't showed (normal) but after the normal is to show up

> if I needed Windows, I would manually select it from the BIOS boot menu. This is how I like it, because I barely use Windows.

It can be done within grub, you don't need to choose that in the BIOS (I'll explain later)

> Today, I booted up and the Grub menu came up after the logo splash screen. I don't know if it got automatically installed in an OS update maybe? But as I understand it, it should be unnecessary, because my OSs are on separate physical drives; is that not the case?

Comes with eOS, is its bootloader. Without it Linux will not boot.

> I've searched around for how to remove Grub but all of the instructions I've found are for removing Linux entirely, which of course I don't want to do.

Because Linux needs a bootloader. In this case is Grub

> How do I go back to booting directly to Linux? And, how do I prevent Grub from getting automatically added like this, if indeed it is part of a routine OS update?

Grub isn't added, when you installed elementaryOS you installed grub because you installed elementaryOS. Like you installed the Linux kernel because you installed elementaryOS. There are other bootloaders that you can install like lilo, burg or syslinux but they do the same

Windows also has his own bootloader called "Windows boot manager", you see it (part of it) everytime you choose the path to boot into safe mode

---

### Your solution

is not to "remove grub" or "choose windows in the BIOS". Is basically to use grub and configure it properly.

You can hide Grub's menu so it will not show even with multiple OS installed

- Edit (I will use `nano` you choose your editor)

  ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
  ```
- Change the line where it says `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE`, should look like this

  ```
   GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
  ```

, you probably had `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu`

- Update Grub

  ```
   sudo update-grub
  ```
- Then in the future, when you want to start Windows (or see grub's menu) just let the system boot and after the BIOS POST press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> (like you press <kbd>DEL</kbd> when you want to enter BIOS) and will show grub and there you can choose another OS to boot, in your case Windows

---

As reference;

[GRUB manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html)

Recommend to watch (Youtube):

[Linux Boot Process: Grub, initrd, explained.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qIEGavnI-B4)

[The Linux Boot Process](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RdbyPwo4W2E)

Comment: I would rather not see `grub` and enjoy the luxury of 2 separate drives by choosing disk from the boot menu.